# Media Queries Flash Banner Q

Tags: media

Quick question: I have a flash banner which is 1000px wide. I'm wanting that when a user's screen (like a smartphone) is less than 1000px, a image is substituted. How can I accomplish that?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hide the flash banner and show display the image when width is less than 1000px using this code in css:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
#flash_banner {display:block;}
#image {display:none;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:999px) {
#flash_banner {display:none;}
#image {display:block;}
}
```

Hope it works well for you.